# Parameter to an image

Tags: c#, wpf

How to add a parameter for an image to this variable?

```
var selectionDisplay = new SelectionDisplay(button.Label as string);
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I have this set of images and their respective code below (see pic1)

This is where the program gets the images to be displayed. The code for the buttons is this one:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(@".\GalleryImages");
                     foreach (var file in files)
                     {
                             FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);
                             BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
                             bi.BeginInit();
                             bi.UriSource = new Uri(file, UriKind.Relative);
                             bi.EndInit();
                             var button = new KinectTileButton
                             {
                                     Label = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file),
                                     Background = new ImageBrush(bi)
                             };
                             this.wrapPanel.Children.Add(button);
                     }
```

This is where the program gets the images to be displayed.
The code for the buttons is this one:

```
private void KinectTileButtonclick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
             var button = (KinectTileButton)e.fake_fake_fakeource;
             var selectionDisplay = new SelectionDisplay(button.Label as string);
             this.kinectRegionGrid.Children.Add(selectionDisplay);
             e.Handled = true;
```

Right now, when i click on of the images, the SelectionDisplay window pops up, which look like this (see pic2). What i want is that when I click an image the SelectionDisplay  window should open with the respective image... meaning that if I click on the image with a dog, the window should open with the dog's image, not with other image.

I hope I've made myself clear and that you can help me.

http://i58.tinypic.com/8zl6h3.jpg
http://i57.tinypic.com/208fosy.png

Comment: Could you be more clear as to what you are trying to do (perhaps some pseudocode)? Its very hard to understand what you are asking.

Comment: Agreed with @LordTakkera, there's not enough here for people to help you. Please add more information.

Comment: Great edit, this is the right way to respond to closing! I'll think about it and answer if this question gets reopened!

Comment: and what should i do in order for the question to be reopened? i apologize, but i'm new on this forum and this is my first post

Comment: Because your question was closed (technically put "on hold"), you need 5 members of the community to agree that your question is now answerable (you have 2, including myself, as of this posting). When you get enough "reopen" votes, people will again be able to answer the question. By posting the edit, you have done as much as you can to get the question reopened. If you can think of anything to improve the question, re-edit, but I think you stand a good chance of making it!

Comment: Re-opened, and answered! Welcome to StackOverflow, and thanks for responding so positively to the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

is this the constructor you are talking about? is this where i should make changes? should i add something after "string itemid"?

```
public SelectionDisplay(string itemId)
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.messageTextBlock.Text = string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,Properties.Resources.SelectedMessage,itemId);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two approaches:

1. Just pass the image brush in your constructor. Its view->view, so you aren't breaking MVVM (and it looks like you aren't using that pattern anyways).

   ```
   new SelectionDisplay(button.Label, button.Background);
   ```
2. Set the path as the "tag" of the button. The tag property is an object you can put whatever you want into (the framework does not use it, and so it is included for this very purpose). Then just pass the string to SelectionDisplay, and instantiate the image just like you are doing for the button:

   ```
   var button = new KinectTileButton
   {
        Label = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file),
        Background = new ImageBrush(bi),
        Tag = file
   };
   var selectionDisplay = new SelectionDisplay(button.Label as string, button.Tag as string);
   ```

FrameworkElement.Tag on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (Note that Button derives from FrameworkElement, as do all controls, so it automatically has it as well!)

**UPDATE**
I see that SelectionDisplay is a UserControl in your project, so you just need to change its constructor to look like:

Numbers match above:

1. SelectionDisplay(string labelText, ImageBrush sourceImage)
2. SelectionDisplay(string labelText, string imagePath)

That is the source of the error you are getting, you have to modify the constructor to take the new parameter.

Please let me know if I can clarify anything.

Comment: i don't understand where i should make these changes... i should mention that i'm a beginner. I've attached another image.. perhaps you can explain better where i should make the changes (i don't want to ruin something)  http://i61.tinypic.com/fng2sp.jpg

Comment: The sample code was meant to replace the similar lines in the code you posted. Obviously you will also have to change the signature of the constructor as well, but that code was not included. Does that make sense?

Comment: http://i61.tinypic.com/b6ztye.png http://i58.tinypic.com/28uqvso.png look at the images to see how i've made the changes and what error i get

Comment: You need to modify the constructor of the control, see my update.